# How to get the true client IP when a reverse proxy sets the value in a custom header rather than in X-Forwarded-For (HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)

Tags: 9

I was working with a Drupal site that sits behind a load balancer and a varnish cache - 2 proxies. The true client IP is not present in the `X-Forwarded-For` header (`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'`) but is present in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`

The IP that Drupal detects is interestingly from some hostname lookup and not present in any of the `$_SERVER` variables.

I don't have control over the infrastructure team to fix the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` at the network level. I will need to fix it in settings.php. Now that Symfony is handling the IP detection, was wondering what `$_SERVER` variable should be altered in settings.php to get Drupal to detect the actual client IP.

Comment: I deleted my answer as not really answering the question. If Apache, you can try copying one header value to another with a technique like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703952/how-to-convert-a-http-header-into-another A technique like that will provide HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR from the HTTP_X_REAL_IP value before the request reaches Drupal.

Comment: I believe you can set $_SERVER variables directly in settings.php and printing $_SERVER seems to be printing the revised variables. I tried setting HTTP_X_REAL_IP as the first item in the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR variable (comma separated string) but did not seem to help. Might need to read through how symfony parses these header values to really figure this out. Was wondering if somebody already has this figured out.

Comment: If PHP does not get `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']`, there is not much you can do. You can set it with another value from `$_SERVER`, assuming it contains an equivalent value.

Comment: This does not seem a question which requires Drupal expertise to be answered. Drupal does not have control over the values contained in `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @apaderno. Maybe the question will need edits. The scenario is that Drupal is not getting the true client IP because of the way the headers come to the application. The question is to figure out what we should alter in $_SERVER to make the symfony request processing get the true client IP.

Comment: After setting up the DrupalKernel Drupal's index.php initializes `$request = Request::createFromGlobals()`, and createFromGlobals uses `$_SERVER` directly as `$request = self::createRequestFromFactory($_GET, $_POST, [], $_COOKIE, $_FILES, $_SERVER)`.

Comment: If Drupal does not remove `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` or change that value, there is nothing that can be done from Drupal side. That is why this question does not require Drupal expertise. If the answer does not change for Drupal, it is not on-topic for us.

Comment: The point is to not have my custom code get the IP from the custom header but about having Drupal detect the IP correctly in all places an IP is used. Eg: floods limits, dblog etc. So the question is what do we manipulate in settings.php to get the desired behavior.

Comment: The actual header to edit is X_FORWARDED_FOR. Is that your question?

Comment: Thanks again @cilefen. Am working on this issue now. Will fix this and post the solution to the problem with findings.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Have added my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Drupal detect the IP of the client correctly you will have to update `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` by prefixing the true client IP to it or setting it to the true client IP itself.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] . ', ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

or

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
```

The challenge is that by the time settings.php is parsed, the Request class has already been instantiated and the server variables have already been processed and loaded into the request object. So doing this in settings.php will not help solve the problem.

In index.php

```
$kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
```

settings.php is processed in `$kernel->handle`.

By then `$request` has already been loaded with values from `$_SERVER`

So to make Drupal detect the correct IP you will have to patch index.php to add the below line before `$request` is initialized.

There is likely a PHP OOPs / Symfony approach by overriding some class / extending some class to fix this more appropriately but this will solve the problem.

Comment: The header is `X-Forwarded-For`. `HTTP_ X_FORWARDED_FOR` is a Symfony Framework constant. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: Oh hold on: this isn’t headers. It’s what that header becomes in PHP superglobals. Ignore that comment. But I think the Question needs some cleanup to clarify HTTP header vs header-as-transformed into a $_SERVER value.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Does that look better now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.